# C: position of field of struct inside a union

Tags: c, struct, unions, specifications

I have the following type:

```
union {
  struct {
    uint32_t c0;
    uint32_t k0[4];
    uint32_t c1;
    uint32_t v[2];
    uint32_t i[2];
    uint32_t c2;
    uint32_t k1[4];
    uint32_t c3;
  } named;
  uint32_t array[16];
} state;
```

because each field inside "named" has a meaning upon initialization, but I will use it mostly as a word array after that. Does C guarantees that `state.array[0]` is the same as `state.named.c0`, `state.array[1]` is `state.named.k0[0]` and so on?

If not, how likely is it to work? Are there any compiler/platform that break my code if I rely on it?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your most worrisome question, "..how likely is it to work", don't gamble on likelihood unless it is a *sure* thing. It isn't in this case.

The standard (§6.7.2.1,p15) dictates the address of the *first* member of a struct, or of *all* members of a union, is the same as of the struct or union itself. For you this only means the address of `array[16]` and `named` are identical, and both are equivalent to the address of `state`. However, without implementation-dependent packing, there is no guarantee that the *struct* will overlay precisely, as the same section of the standard calls out that inter-structure packing is possible.

For example, for whatever reason a compiler working with a packing scheme to always start members on 64bit boundaries could lay out your `name` as follows:

```
struct {
    uint32_t c0;
    **padding 4 bytes**
    uint32_t k0[4];
    uint32_t c1;
    **padding 4 bytes**
    uint32_t v[2];
    uint32_t i[2];
    uint32_t c2;
    **padding 4 bytes**
    uint32_t k1[4];
    uint32_t c3;
    **padding 4 bytes**
} name;
```

In short, all you are guaranteed is that the memory occupied by `name` *as a whole* and the memory occupied by the other member of your union, `array[16]` shall occupy the same memory, starting at the beginning addressable location of each. What that memory looks like under the covers of `name`'s packing is up to the implementation and any packing hints you care to supply.

Some of the relevant portions of the standard:

> **C99-§6.7.2.1,p6** 
>   As discussed in 6.2.5, a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, whose storage is allocated in an ordered sequence, and a union is a type consisting of a sequence of members whose storage overlap.
>
> **C99-§6.7.2.1,p15**
>   Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.
>
> **C99-§6.7.2.1,p16**
>   The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members (or if a member is a bit- field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>
> **C99-§6.7.2.1,p17**
>   There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

Comment: Size of array is 4x16=64 bytes and "minimal" size of struct is 64 also. So is it possible to add some directive or so to say struct size is 64 ? Therefore, behavior will be the one expected. No ?

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard:

> **6.7.2.1/15**
>   Within a structure object, the non-bit-ﬁeld members and the units in which bit-ﬁelds
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a
>   bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.
>
> **6.7.2.1/16**
>   The size of a union is sufﬁcient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at
>   most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. **A pointer to a
>   union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members** (or if a member is a bit-
>   ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

Emphasis mine. This basically translates into `state.named`, `state.named.c0`, and `state.array` having the same address. However, and here's the catch, there is no guarantee about where the rest of `named`'s members lie (*order* in memory is specified, but *location* is not). There can, technically, be padding in between each of `named`'s members (and even at the end of `named` as well). So the answer is **no, that is not guaranteed.** Padding can be added in between your members.

The key is the last sentence of the first quote:

> **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object**

Answer (score -3):

yes `state.array[0]` is same as `state.named.c0`. C guarantees that 'array[16]` and structure named would occupy same area of memory.

This is true as long as data type are matching. for e.g if you are storing 2 sorts and then read a integer the result is machine dependent.

Comment: No, there can be padding in between the members of `named`.